# Where is the home for virtualenv script?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I noticed that

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```

installed the script into
~/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts/.env35/bin though virtual
environment .env35 (created earlier) was not active at the time of
issuing the command.

From ~/.profile

```
PATH="/home/gsmith/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts/.env35/bin:$PATH"
export WORKON_HOME=~/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts/.env35
```

what is the correct place (dir) where virtualenv is installed? I would
think that virualenv script should not depend on whether I have created
virtual environments or not. Is this correct?

Please also clarify the following. Each created (by virtualenv)
virtual environment has bin and site-packages subdirs. ~/.local also
does. I understand that when I use

```
(.env35) $ pip3 install aiohttp
```

a package is installed into the active virtual environment.

When ~/.local is used? Should I setup something additionally?

Using:
Python 3.5.3; 
Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)

UPDATED 04/29
Through experiment found that if no virtual environments found in the PATH variable, pip3 installs virtualenv script into ~/.local/bin

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Why are you trying to `pip install virtualenv` when you apparently already have a virtualenv activated? Normally you shouldn't be putting anything in your `.profile` unless, say, you wanted to always activate some virtualenv on login (and in this case I would still use `source `~/.env35/bin/activate` rather than setting some environment variables manually if you're not sure what you're doing).

Comment: I have problems with old configuration. Completion is extremely slow. Elpy happens to hang. I'm creating a new configuration.

Comment: `~/.local` is a little bit like a virtualenv in that it's an alternate `/usr`-like directory structure in your home directory that you can install packages into when using things like `pip install --user`. The name `.local` is just a convention and is I think a default prefix in various cases. But it's nothing directly to do with virtualenv.

Comment: $pip3 install --user virtualenv
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.

Comment: There's no reason to do that. I was just explaining what `.local` refers to as opposed to a virtualenv. There's no reason to use it if you're already using a virtualenv. I think it's not clear what you're trying to do or what problem you're having.